# Nodemailer use specific outboung port

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm having issues sending email from nodemailer due to the company firewall.
I'm using the default configuration of nodemailer but I get a timeout error, and seems that the problem is due to the server/firewall is configured only allow outbound traffic to go through port 587.

Is there any way to configure nodemailer to use this specific outgoing port and not a random one?

Comment: Ok so I found a solution to solve the problem of the company firewall. Based on Matt response that it was not possible on the nodemailer I've created an iptables rule to redirect the request to open port and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The [destination `port` defaults](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#general-options) to 587. If `secure: true` is set, 465.

```
nodemailer.createTransport({ host: 'mx', port: 465, secure: true })
```

TCP source ports are chosen randomly by the host, but that's nothing to do with nodemailer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, so if nodemailer has nothing to do with source port, I need to use another way, like iptables, to force the traffic to use this one right?